# MYSQL Select query from Node JS is giving wrong value for datetime column

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, lambda

Datetime value saved column START_DATE in mysql table : 2022-01-01 00:00:00

Response object after executing select query

SELECT * FROM tablename

RowDataPacket {
ID: 1,
START_DATE: 2021-12-31T16:00:00.000Z,
},

here mysql is auto converted the date and given a wrong date value as a response.That is 2021-12-31T16:00:00.000Z instead of 2022-01-01 00:00:00. Anyone know the reason for this issue and how we can fix the same ?
Note :
DB is connected from a Node JS lambda application using mysql pool connection

Comment: check for the timezone of your mysql server. I believe the server is in CST and you are in ISR that is why there is a difference of 4 hrs

Comment: No , Its same timezone only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the timezone. While retrieving the datetime from database it is converting to GMT.
To fix this issue we need to mention timezone as 'utc' while establishing the connection

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.0.0.1',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin123',
    database: 'mydb',
    timezone: 'utc' //<-- Add timezone
  });
```